# yield MemoryLeaks

Tags: c#

Решил я попробовать использовать `yield` в своем проекте и столкнулся с проблемой утечки памяти.

Вот пример кода с использованием `yield`:

```
public IEnumerable<ExportImage> ProcessMultipleExportImagesMultipleSrcCrop(IEnumerable<ExportImage> bitmaps)
{
    int nok = 1;
    foreach (var pos in Settings.ImagesReferences)
    {
        nok = NOK(nok, pos.Length);
    }
    nok = NOK(nok, bitmaps.Count());

    for (int i = 0; i < nok; i++)
    {
        yield return ProcessSingleExportImageCropSrc(bitmaps.ElementAt(i % bitmaps.Count()), i);
    }
}
```

А вот без:

```
public IEnumerable<ExportImage> ProcessMultipleExportImagesMultipleSrcCrop(IEnumerable<ExportImage> bitmaps)
{
    int nok = 1;
    foreach (var pos in Settings.ImagesReferences)
    {
        nok = NOK(nok, pos.Length);
    }
    nok = NOK(nok, bitmaps.Count());

    var res = new List<ExportImage>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nok; i++)
    {
        res.Add( ProcessSingleExportImageCropSrc(bitmaps.ElementAt(i % bitmaps.Count()), i));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Код обрабатывающий результат:

```
var tmpres = ImageConcatenator.ProcessMultipleExportImagesMultipleSrcCrop(frames);
var res = new SafeIntPtrArray<ExportImage> { Values = tmpres.ToArray(), Size = tmpres.Count() };
foreach (var item in frames)
{
    item.Dispose();
}
await Render(res);
```

В первом случае я получаю утечку памяти при каждом вызове, во втором нет.
Вся память корректно освобождается без использования GC, так как `ExportImage` структура из C библиотеки, так что GC винить в этом наверное не целесообразно.

В чем может быть проблема? Ибо хотелось бы использовать `yield`, но если с ним такие трудности возникают, то толка нету. Я понимаю, что это я где-то неверно что-то неправильно делаю, но понять не могу. Так что жду подсказки.

P.S. Могу предположить, что при вызове `tmpres.ToArray()` где-то там и происходит утечка, но как от нее избавиться?

Comment: Два вопроса. Что такое frames? Что возвращает ProcessSingleExportImageCropSrc и не надо ли его освобождать тоже?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле утечка происходит вот тут: `tmpres.Count()`. Скорее всего, у вас утекает результат вызова `ProcessSingleExportImageCropSrc`, но могу и ошибаться.

Вызов `Count()` приводит к полному выполнению вашего генератора, открывается куча ресурсов - которые вы никогда не закрываете!

Правильнее внешний код писать вот так:

```
var tmpres = ImageConcatenator.ProcessMultipleExportImagesMultipleSrcCrop(frames).ToArray();
var res = new SafeIntPtrArray<ExportImage> { Values = tmpres, Size = tmpres.Length };
foreach (var item in frames)
{
    item.Dispose();
}
await Render(res);
```

Обратите внимание: материализующий вызов - только один, `ToArray()`, второго вызова не делается.